# How to implement a twitter app to tweet through abraham/twitteroauth

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am a very newbie to oAuth, PHP and Twitter programming. I am trying to develop one twitter app with Abraham Twitteroauth library. I have downloaded the source code from https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth and I have put that in my WAMP's www location. 
My config.php is

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * A single location to store configuration.
 */

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'nVD<hidden>');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'DKTAW17fwK<hidden>');
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://127.0.0.1/twitteroauth-master/twitteroauth-master/sdf.php');
?>
```

I am pretty much sure about the Consumer key and secret as I get the login page. The sdf.php is the file where I used to make tweet

```
    <?php
    /**
     * @file
     * 
     */

    /* Load required lib files. */
    session_start();
    require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
    require_once('config.php');

    /* If access tokens are not available redirect to connect page. */
    if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
        header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
    }
    /* Get user access tokens out of the session. */
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

    /* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

    /* If method is set change API call made. Test is called by default. */
    $content = $connection->get('account/rate_limit_status');
    echo "Current API hits remaining: {$content->remaining_hits}.";

    /* Get logged in user to help with tests. */
    $user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

    $active = FALSE;
    if (empty($active) || empty($_GET['confirmed']) || $_GET['confirmed'] !== 'TRUE') {
      echo '<h1>Warning! This page will make many requests to Twitter.</h1>';
      echo '<h3>Performing these test might max out your rate limit.</h3>';
      echo '<h3>Statuses/DMs will be created and deleted. Accounts will be un/followed.</h3>';
      echo '<h3>Profile information/design will be changed.</h3>';
      echo '<h2>USE A DEV ACCOUNT!</h2>';
      echo '<h4>Before use you must set $active = TRUE in test.php</h4>';
      echo '<a href="./test.php?confirmed=TRUE">Continue</a> or <a href="./index.php">go back</a>.';
      exit;
    }

    function twitteroauth_row($method, $response, $http_code, $parameters = '') {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo "<td><b>{$method}</b></td>";
      switch ($http_code) {
        case '200':
        case '304':
          $color = 'green';
          break;
        case '400':
        case '401':
        case '403':
        case '404':
        case '406':
          $color = 'red';
          break;
        case '500':
        case '502':
        case '503':
          $color = 'orange';
          break;
        default:
          $color = 'grey';
      }
      echo "<td style='background: {$color};'>{$http_code}</td>";
      if (!is_string($response)) {
        $response = print_r($response, TRUE);
      }
      if (!is_string($parameters)) {
        $parameters = print_r($parameters, TRUE);
      }
      echo '<td>', strlen($response), '</td>';
      echo '<td>', $parameters, '</td>';
      echo '</tr><tr>';
      echo '<td colspan="4">', substr($response, 0, 400), '...</td>';
      echo '</tr>';

    }

    function twitteroauth_header($header) {
      echo '<tr><th colspan="4" style="background: grey;">', $header, '</th></tr>';
    }

    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$parameters = array('status' => date(DATE_RFC822));
$status = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
twitteroauth_row('statuses/update', $status, $connection->http_code, $parameters);

    ?>
```

I copy pasted this line from test.php.
The problem I have is, when I go to the homepage, sign-in, it again redirect me to the connect.php. And it seems like its not saving any sessions. Please help me tp overcome this.

Comment: Don't use test.php. Follow the [extended flow using example code](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth#extended-flow-using-example-code). It covers exactly how to authenticate someone and index.php has an example for creating a status.

Comment: Hi @abraham can you please help me by posting a working example to make tweet. I am just a beginner and struggling to make this

Comment: The link in my comment is a working example to tweet.

Comment: I bag your help http://twittercleanx.azurewebsites.net/ I have done everything here. but this is again and again redirecting me to http://twittercleanx.azurewebsites.net/connect.php even after successfull login. I have sent you an email regarding this. Since I am very new to Twitter PHP OAuth programming. Please give me a working solution with modified index.php file.

Comment: This is a working solution: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/index.php